# Spring AOP and ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConvertingComparator

Tags: spring, aspectj, classnotfoundexception, spring-aop

I am trying to switch our project from AspectJ to Spring AOP. We're using AspectJ annotations and method execution point cuts which are supported by Spring AOP. We had no problems with compile-time weaving but we are trying to get rid of unnecessary build steps.

I have added
 to our Spring configuration files and removed the weaver plugin from our pom.xml. The result is a very strange error that seems to be unique (i.e. Google did not know about it):

```
19:05:19,213 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-4) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConvertingComparator
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:734) [spring-context-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:457) [spring-context-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) [spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) [spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [classes.jar:1.6.0_43]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [classes.jar:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_43]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConvertingComparator
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConvertingComparator
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.<clinit>(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:74) [spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.<init>(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:53) [spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [classes.jar:1.6.0_43]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) [classes.jar:1.6.0_43]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [classes.jar:1.6.0_43]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [classes.jar:1.6.0_43]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConvertingComparator from [Module "deployment.api-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 29 more
```

These are our configuration files:

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:spring/*.xml"/>

    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
    </bean>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="xyz.censored"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

spring-dao.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:spring/jdbc.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver_class}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}?characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate is used as JPA vendor -->
    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Entity manager -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="xyz.censored"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure transaction management -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="aspectj"/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="xyz.censored"/>
</beans>
```

spring-aspects.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:spring-configured/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <bean id="stringTranslationInterceptor" class="xyz.censored.aspects.StringTranslationInterceptor"/>

    <bean id="translationAspect" class="xyz.censored.aspects.TranslationAspect">
        <property name="translationInterceptors">
            <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="xyz.censored.aspects.TranslationInterceptor">
                <entry key="java.lang.String" value-ref="stringTranslationInterceptor"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

What is the problem? I'm stuck. :(

**EDIT:**

partlov suggested to get rid of other versions of Spring. I did this by explicitly excluding some dependencies. The exception is now gone, but the former AspectJ aspects are ignored by Spring. Is there anything wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Looks like you have different versions of Spring modules, some of them are 3.1.4 and some 3.2.1. Be shore you are using same version for all parts of Spring.

Comment: I have manually excluded some 3.1.4 versioned dependencies (it's strange that Spring artifacts that have the version 3.2.1 depend on other artifacts that have the version 3.1.4 but that is another story). The exception disappeared, but the aspects aren't found/used/applied. :( Is there something wrong with the configuration files (order of tags, wrong tags, missing tags, ...)?

Answer (score 2):

This error seems to be due to the different versions of the spring modules. Please make sure that you are using the same spring version for different spring modules in you pom.xml. For e.g. spring-web, spring-webmvc, spring-aop should have same spring version. Let me know if this resolves your problem else post your pom.xml file to analyze it further.

Comment: yes, I beleive it's the root of the problem. It solved my problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConvertingComparator is caused because your jar which has org.springframework.core.convert.converter.convertingComparator has actually no class defined for it..Try downloading different version of that jar which has ConvertingComparator and run again